# Filtering Dropdown list in mvc razor with jQuery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two controls on the page one for country and one for state. Once the country dropdown is changed I have this AJAX function that will return States or Provincese. I want to keep all the ValidationMessageFor and the selectedStateId in the control just looking to fill the drop down. there a way to add the option value for the select control?  Any Help would be great.

View

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.selectedStateId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.selectedStateId,
    new SelectList("","StateId", "Name"),
    "-- please select a States or Provincese --",
    new { id = "ddlStates", @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.selectedCountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

js

```
$("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
        var countryId = $(this).val();
        console.log(countryId);
        loadstates(countryId);
    });

    function loadstates(countryId) {
           var strUrl = '@Url.Action("GetStates", "RequestForm")';
            $.ajax({
                url: strUrl,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                data: {countryId: countryId},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#ddlStates").html($(data).html());
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("error occured");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Then instead of `.html()` use `.append()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cascading dropdown lists,we usually return a list in ajax,and put them into option,and put options to dropdownlist with `append()`(As Swati says).Here is a working demo:

View:

```
<form>
    <select id="ddlCountry">
        <option value="1">Country1</option>
        <option value="2">Country2</option>
        <option value="3">Country3</option>

    </select>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.selectedStateId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.selectedStateId,
        new SelectList("", "StateId", "Name"),
        "-- please select a States or Provincese --",
        new { id = "ddlStates", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.selectedCountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</form>
```

js:

```
$("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
        var countryId = $(this).val();
        console.log(countryId);
        loadstates(countryId);
    });

    function loadstates(countryId) {
           var strUrl = '@Url.Action("GetStates", "RequestForm")';
            $.ajax({
                url: strUrl ,
                type: "GET",
                data: {countryId: countryId},
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        var text1 = '<option value=' + value.stateId + '>' +
                            value.name+
                            '</option>';
                        $("#ddlStates").append(text1);
                    });
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("error occured");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Model:

```
public class Address {
        public int selectedStateId { get; set; }
        public int selectedCountryId { get; set; }

    }
    public class State
    {
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Action(I use fake data to test):

```
public List<State> GetStates(int countryId)
        {
            List<State> states = new List<State> { new State { StateId = 1, Name = "state1" }, new State { StateId = 2, Name = "state2" }, new State { StateId = 3, Name = "state3" } };
            return states;
        }
```

result:
[image]